# Adding kotlinx-datetime to my Kotlin Multiplatform app breaks iOS build

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kmm

I was able to successfully run the sample app generated by Android Studio in both Android and iOS. I chose CocoaPods during the Wizard steps.

But when  I add [kotlinx-datetime](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx-datetime) to my dependencies, I can only run the app for Android.

My build.gradle.kts :

```
    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-datetime:0.3.0")
            }
        }
    ...
```

When adding the library I get the following error:

```
> Task :shared:linkDebugFrameworkIosX64 FAILED
e: Compilation failed: Expecting descriptor for kotlin.time/TimeMark.<init>|-5645683436151566731[0]

 * Source files: 
 * Compiler version info: Konan: 1.7.0 / Kotlin: 1.7.20
 * Output kind: STATIC_CACHE

e: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expecting descriptor for kotlin.time/TimeMark.<init>|-5645683436151566731[0]
```

How to reproduce:

1. Create a KMM sample app with AS.
2. Add the library : **implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-datetime:0.3.0")** to the commonMain in the build.gradle.kts
3. Try to use/import/print LocalDate in any way

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 5):

After upgrading to Kotlin 1.7.0 and using kotlinx-datetime 0.3.2, I started to face the same issue.

As suggested [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-52554), upgrading to `org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-datetime:0.3.3` solved the issue.